# Can params field that is not part of params.require.permit be modified by user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, validation, permissions

If I have nested resources, such as

```
resources :club do
    resources :agenda
end
```

and their relationships are as follow:

```
 club has_many agendas  
 agenda belongs_to club
```

If my agenda's create action takes in `params[:club_id]` and assign it to agenda's club reference, is it safe to assume that user cannot modify that field (club_id is not part of my `params.require.permit`)?

What I mean is, do I still need to check whether the club_id belongs to the current user before creating the an agenda with `params[:club_id]`, or can I trust that `params[:club_id]` cannot be tampered with by the user.

I'm worried that a user can create an agenda from another club simply by modifying the params' hashes.

fyi, some related gems I'm using are devise and cancan.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to read up on [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) (great [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) about it here)

---

**System**

Then you need to ensure your *system* is set up correctly:

If `users` cannot modify specific resources, you need authorization *before* they're able to edit / submit them. To do this, you can use the [`cancan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem to determine whether a user can edit / create a resource at controller level:

```
  #app/controllers/agendas_controller.rb
  load_and_authorize_resource
```

This firstly ensures you're able to determine if the `current_user` is actually able to change the `club` to begin with

---

**Params**

The second thing to do is ensure your `params` are handled correctly

[`strong params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) basically allows you to send specific params through to your model, which includes the `club_id`.

The problem you have is you don't want someone injecting a different param *after* the form has been submitted. To prevent this, you should **only assign `club_id` in your controller** - this will ensure the front-end cannot set the value:

params.require(:adgenda).permit(:your, :params).merge(club_id: params[:club_id])

By setting the value in the controller, it means only the server has access to the value, allowing you to submit it accordingly

This, coupled with the front-end authorization, should provide a base level of security for your app

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying that user cannot modify the same 'params[:club_id]' sent along with form, they can only send a follow up 'params[:club_id]' (making the params[:club_id]' sent with form different from the one injected after the form is submitted)?  
Because even in the controller, you are still using params[:club_id]. How do you know that the params[:club_id] you are using in controller hasn't been tampered with? Is that where strong parameter comes in?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how params and strong parameters work. Either: "params are pre-populated with values, user modifies any of the values of params (all attributes are modifiable), and when mass-assigning, only permitted attributes are updated with values from params (other params values are modified)."
OR
"params are pre-populated with values, user cannot update all attributes in params (only the ones allowed in permit), and only the ones allowed in permit is assigned in mass-assignment (other params values are untouched).". Which, if any, is the correct understanding?